# How to round down if number is even and round up if odd?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a page to round up an odd decimal number and round down an even decimal number. So I am having problems checking if the decimal number is even or odd by check the first number 5 of the 5.8 typed. Then display the original number along with the adjusted number(round up or down) depending on the even or odd number. Along side with the rounded number like 4.8 is 5 or 7.2 is 7.

I have tried using if statement using the original number % 2 == 0 and it keeps saying 0.

```js
function roundIt() {
  // initializes variables
  var orgNum = 0,
    adjNum = 0,
    rounNum = 0;
  // prompts user to enter a number
  orgNum = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a number"));
  alert("Orginial Num: " + orgNum);
  // uses orginal number to then round up if odd and round down if even
  while (orgNum != -99) {
    // if statement to even (floor) and use odd (ceil)
    isEven(orgNum);
    rounNum = Math.round(orgNum);
    // display results 
    document.write("<p>Orginial Number: " + orgNum);
    document.write("<br>Adjusted Number: " + adjNum);
    document.write("<br>Rounded Number: " + rounNum + "</p>");

    // prompts user to enter a number
    orgNum = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a number"));
  }
}
// function to see if number is even or odd
function isEven(orgNum) {
  if ((orgNum % 2) == 0) {
    adjNum = Math.floor(orgNum);
    alert("Even Num: " + adjNum);
  } else {
    adjNum = Math.ceil(orgNum);
    alert("Odd Num: " + adjNum);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p><input type="button" class="button button2" value="Click to start" onclick="roundIt();" />
  </p>
</div>
```

My results should look like this :

```
Original Number: 6.6
Adjusted number: 6
Rounded number: 7

Original Number: 5.8
Adjusted number: 5
Rounded number: 6
```

but i get this:

```
Orginial Number: 5.8
Adjusted Number: 0
Rounded Number: 6

Orginial Number: 6.6
Adjusted Number: 0
Rounded Number: 7
```

Comment: what you think `5.8%2` and `6.6%2` would be?

Comment: erm? looks like what you want is "Adjusted" being Math.floor and Rounded being `Math.ceil` or `Math.round` - there's not enough info in your sample data to say otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusted value seems to be the result of `parseInt(v*10, 10) % 2 == 0 ? Math.floor(v) : Math.ceil(v),` but your sample data is too small to be sure

```js
function rounder(v) {
  return {
    original: v,
    adjusted: parseInt(v*10, 10) % 2 == 0 ? Math.floor(v) : Math.ceil(v),
    rounded: Math.round(v)
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(rounder(6.6), null, 4));
console.log(JSON.stringify(rounder(5.8), null, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a relatively inefficient way to do it, but one that should work efficiently. The entire internet is gonna yell at me for this one ;-;

So what you can do is have JavaScript read your float as a string, slice off everything after the period, and take only the ones digit. For example, in the number 27.732, it would take off the decimal and everything before the 7 in the ones place, then have it check for if that number is either 1, 3, 5, etc. or 0, 2, 4, etc. That's the simplest way I can think of, all it's doing is checking if the last digit before the decimal is even or odd.

Let me take a crack at the code...

```
var number = 34.52;

String(number);

var x = number.split(".").trim();
if (len(x[0]) > 1) {
    var number2 = x[0].slice(len(x[0]) - 1);
} else {
    var number2 = x[0];
}

Number(number)
Number(number2)

if (number2 == 1 || number2 == 3 || number2 == 5 || number2 == 7 || number2 == 9) {
    Math.floor(number);
} else {
    Math.ceiling(number);
}
```

Comment: an array does not have a `trim` method, your code fails at `var x = number.split(".").trim();` - you're also rounding down for odd and up for even - complete opposite to requirements - and the question states that the rounding depends on the first decimal digit, not the unit digit

Comment: yeah i figured something was going to be wrong there. although the part about rounding dependency was more at the fault of misinterpretation